# How to make the logic of the social media feed efficient?

Tags: django, django-models

I want to do something similar to Twitter in which the last posts of the people you follow in a feed come out, and these posts appear. These are my relationships:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    bio = models.TextField(max_length=300, blank=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name="posts", on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    content = models.TextField(max_length=300)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

class Follow(models.Model):
    follower = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="following", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    following = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="followers", on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def unicode(self):
        return "{} follows {}".format(self.follower, self.following)
```

I'm looking for a filter that would be efficient when handling large amounts of data.

What would I need to do to get the posts from my followers, and then sorting them by most recent?

Comment: It would be far more efficient to create a self-referencing ManyToManyField in the Profile model to replace the Follow model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you changed your models to provide your own [custom user model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/customizing/#using-a-custom-user-model-when-starting-a-project) and you create the following/followers relationship to a non-symmetrical [ManyToManyField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField) you could simplify your models quite a lot

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser


class User(AbstractUser):

    following = models.ManyToManyField('self', related_name='followers', symmetrical=False)

    bio = models.TextField(max_length=300, blank=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)


class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="posts", on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    content = models.TextField(max_length=300)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

In your settings

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'app.User'
```

Now in your view you can easily query the users that the user is following

```
request.user.following.all()
```

And to query the posts from all the users that the user is following

```
Post.objects.filter(user__followers=request.user).order_by('-created')
```